# Why can't I boot to live USB anymore?

Tags: dual-boot, usb, bios

There is not much to say. After I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, I am unable to boot to a live USB! I used to do it all the time before I installed Ubuntu. I am unable to find an answer online. I don't have the option in BIOS to boot to USB anymore like I used to. And there is no USB option to enable or disable in BIOS.

So whats going on here? How can I fix the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to boot? If Win and Ubuntu are both set to efi and  legacy is not enabled, if the usb only has legacy you won't see it in the boot menu. (Note: if that's it, not recommending to enable legacy unless you really need it)

Comment: Well, in what way does it not work? Do you get to the BIOS boot menu, select the USB, and just have it continue to GRUB?

Comment: I am trying to boot to Kali linux.  And legacy is not enabled.

Comment: The usb is NOT showing up at all in the BIOS boot menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE :**
Older versions of Kali Linux distros did not have EFI support. In this special case you have to enable legacy support in BIOS. The procedure to do this varies depending on the vendor setup.

If you have an EFI supported version of Kali Linux such as the [**rolling-edition**](https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-rolling-edition-2016-1/), follow these steps to create a bootable USB. In this example I consider the USB drive as **`/dev/sdb1`** - it may vary, so execute `sudo fdisk -l` to determine your USB drive.

First un-mount the USB disk : `umount /dev/sdb1`

Create the bootable USB disk :

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/Your-kali-iso/kali-linux-2016.1-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=512k && sync
```

The dd command provides no feedback until the process is completed, but if your drive has an access indicator, you will see it flickering from time to time. The output will be something like:

```
5618+1 records in
5618+1 records out
2945482752 bytes (2.9 GB, 2.7 GiB) copied, 287.421 s, 10.2 MB/s
```

Now you should see your USB pendrive in BIOS.